# Optimising Strings and nested searches

Tags: java, string, optimization, nested

I've been working on a function that is searching heirarchally organised text.  Since the files I'm working with are large in both size and number, the matter of optimisation (both speed and memory) is becoming increasingly important and I'm looking on how to improve an algorithm

```
public NestLink<String> searchsubs(String input, NestLink<String> searchTags) {

// parameter tests

int startIndex = 0; // start of the resultant subsection
int endIndex = 0; // end of the resultant subsection
String openTag = searchTags.elem1; // start of the string I need
String closeTag = searchTags.elem2; // end of the string I need
String subString = null; // stores the result in between
NestLink<String> node = null; // temp variable
NestLink<String> out = null; // output variable

while (true) {
    // find the opening string
    startIndex = input.indexOf(openTag, endIndex);
    if (startIndex == -1) {
    break; // if no more are found, break from the loop
    } else {
    }
    endIndex = input.indexOf(closeTag, startIndex);
    if (endIndex == -1) {
    break; // if tag isn't closed, break from the loop
    } else {
    }

    // we now have a pair of tags with a content between
    subString = input.substring(startIndex + openTag.length(), endIndex);

    // store what we found, method unimportant

    // search this content for each subsearch in the heirarchy
    for (NestLink<String> subSearch : searchTags.subBranches) {
    // recurse
    node = subBlockParser(subString, subSearch);
    // do stuff with results
    }       
}

//final do stuff
return out;
}
```

note: NestLink is a customised tree structure, the format is unimportant, however.

The result is that for each level of the search a copy of the substring, sometimes up to 1mbyte in size, is being created which is obviously far from efficient.

To try and resolve this I considered the following:

```
public NestLink<String> searchsubs(String input, int substringStart, int substringEnd,
NestLink<String> searchTags) {

// parameter tests

int startIndex = substringStart; // start of the resultant subsection
int endIndex = substringStart; // end of the resultant subsection
String openTag = searchTags.elem1; // start of the string I need
String closeTag = searchTags.elem2; // end of the string I need
String subString = null; // stores the result in between
NestLink<String> node = null; // temp variable
NestLink<String> out = null; // output variable

while (true) {
    // find the opening string
    startIndex = input.indexOf(openTag, endIndex);
    if (startIndex == -1 || startIndex >= substringEnd) {
    break; // if no more are found, break from the loop
    } else {
    }
    endIndex = input.indexOf(closeTag, startIndex);
    if (endIndex == -1 || endIndex >= substringEnd) {
    break; // if tag isn't closed, break from the loop
    } else {
    }

    // we now have a pair of tags with a content between
    // store what we found, method unimportant

    // search this content for each subsearch in the heirarchy
    for (NestLink<String> subSearch : searchTags.subBranches) {
    // recurse, this time sharing input, but with a new substring start and end to serve as bounds
    node =
        subBlockParser(input, startIndex + openTag.length(), endIndex, subSearch);
    // do stuff with results
    }
}

// final do stuff
return out;
}
```

This time rather than creating a substring I send the input and a set of bounds.  This raises the question, how would the JRE handle this?   Would it copy the input string (resulting in a reduced performance as an even bigger string is being copied now), or would it simply pass a pointer object as it would with othre objects and all recursions share the same string object (a significant performance increase as there is no copying)

Alternatively, are there any other concepts that may be applicable to a heirarchal search? and heirarchal result?

K.Barad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`substring` doesn't create a new String containing a copy of the chars in the original string. It just returns a String object sharing the same char array as the original string, but with a different offset and length.

So your second implementation is similar to the first one, but more complex (because it does what String does internally).

Comment: I was worried that would be the case, it means the heart of my problem is more that there is an excessive number of large files, more than that they are being handled ineffectively.

Comment: @K.Barad: until you've run a profiler, you DO NOT KNOW what the heart of your problem is. It could just as well be a single line hidden in some sub-sub-sub-method which does something horrendously inefficient in a non-obvious way, which you haven't ever spent a thought on.

Comment: @Michael: Well called, seems the bulk of the delay wasn't this method itself, but the utility that was converting an arraylist of strings into a single string, generating the input of this function.  Trying to turn 8000+ strings into a single one was the bottleneck.  Got a 98% reduction in time by reading the files as a single string in the first place, as there are only a few places where I actually treat them as lines or words, and as that is a smaller number of cases I can afford an extra function to split it there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the Java standard API already implements this optimization, so there is nothing to be gained from it.

A `java.lang.String` consists of an underlying `char[]`, an offset and a length. `substring()` reuses the `char[]` and merely adjusts the offset and length.

I suggest using a profiler on your code to find out where it actually spends most of the time, *before* you think of any optimizations. That will prevent you from wasting your efforts like this, and I can almost guarantee that you will be surprised by the result.